# odd behavior with java collections of parameterized Class objects

Tags: java

Ran into some questionable behavior using lists of parameterized Class objects:

```
ArrayList<Class<String>> classList = new ArrayList<Class<String>>();

classList.add(Integer.class); //compile error

Class intClass = Integer.class;
classList.add(intClass); //legal apparently, as long as intClass is not parameterized
```

Found the same behavior for LinkedList, haven't tried other collections.  Is it like this for a reason?  Or have I stumbled on something?

Comment: I do believe you should be getting a compile warning, not an error at that point. This isn't new, nor questionable. You have dropped information when casting to an unparameterized Class object. The compiler can and will warn you about this, but expects you do your own verification when the Class isn't parameterized. AND, this would probably run, right up until when you fetched the instance from the list. Then you would get a class cast exception.

Comment: Beyond error, why would you use 'Class<String>'? I assume what you really need is 'Class<?>', unless you want classes that are subtypes of a specific type, like 'Class<? extends BaseType>'.

Comment: Possibly a contrived example, as last time I checked String was final, so nothing extends it. Why would you have a list of multiple classes that can only be String.class?

Comment: Thanks for the help with this guys. I was surprised that the compiler would stand by while a Class<B> element wound up in an ArrayList<Class<A>>, but after understanding raw types better it makes sense. And yes my example was contrived..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is legal only as a concession to backward compatibility so that code written before Java 5 can be compiled in 5 or later without going through and adding generics.  Using a raw type for another reason is generally considered a programming error or at least poor style/laziness.

By willfully declaring a Raw Type you're abandoning the compiler's ability to help you with type safety, so you get a warning and it's back on you to make sure things are safe at run time.

Answer (score 0):

This generates an "unchecked conversion" warning.

`Class` (rather than `Class<String>` or `Class<?>` or `Class<Object>`) is a raw type. Raw types can be assigned to from parameterized types without error, but you get a warning. This type of assignment is only a warning so you can have a codebase that's only partially generified. See also [the section of the JLS on raw types](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#110257).